# Reset admin password for Atlassian Crowd

Tags: crowd

Help, we are a small team of 20 trying to get Atlassian Crowd working. The developer who had setup Crowd left the team on a bad note and did not bother to let anyone know the configuration settings for Crowd.

Now, I need to add some users to crowd but cannot login with the admin credentials provided to me. I need to reset the admin password but do not know the type of database used. They do not have mail configured on Crowd either. So I cannot just reset the password.

I am new to this. Can anyone please tell me **how I can find out the type of database being used (whether it is MySQL, HSQL or something else - is there a configuration file holding this info)**?

Reinstalling Crowd is not an option since they use LDAP for logging in. So while we do this, no one would be able to access their emails.

EDIT - I have the link with which I can reset the admin password. But I do not know which steps to follow because I don't know the DB being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the database info in a file called `crowd.cfg.xml`, which is located in the Crowd home directory - it'll have the hibernate properties in XML that contain everything used to configure the database.

(If you're not sure where to find that directory, let me know and we'll track it down.)

Once you have that, you'll be able to follow the Atlassian [documentation on resetting the password directly in the database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDKB/Restoring+Passwords+To+Recover+Admin+User+Rights).

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try something like [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDKB/Restoring+Passwords+To+Recover+Admin+User+Rights)?

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.

Comment: Getting access to the database is the problem. I do not know the type of database used. My question states that I need to find the type of DB used so I can follow the next steps. Thanks.

Comment: I assumed asking a question that can reasonably be answered by a search on google (which is how I found the link in my answer) would also be discouraged. Especially when the answer to the question as indicated in the title is an explicit entry in the documentation of the product in question. The link indicated also shows how to determine whether an internal or external db is in use (though not which external db is in use). With a running crowd the db connection, for an external db, should be detectable with standard system tools (lsof, netstat, etc.).